# describe vs printSchema methods on DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, schema, describe

I am running this code in pyspark and the difference in output between describe and printSchema is confusing. please have a look at the code below.

**The describe() gives score column as string where as when i do describe without parentheses or use printSchema() then it gives score column as int - which it is actually.**

This is my dataframe.

```
>>> df.show()
+-------+------+-----+
|   name|course|score|
+-------+------+-----+
| fsdhfu|     a|   56|
| sdjjfd|     a|   57|
|kljsjlk|     b|   23|
|  udjkx|     b|   89|
|    ias|     c|   36|
| jksdkj|     c|   37|
|  usdkj|     d|   48|
+-------+------+-----+
```

**Using describe:**

```
>>> df2.describe()
DataFrame[summary: string, name: string, course: string, score: string]
>>> df2.describe
<bound method DataFrame.describe of DataFrame[name: string, course: string, score: int]>
```

**Using printSchema:**

```
>>> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- course: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between them is that schema offers you information about the columns, like the name the columns and their data type, whereas describe offers statistics about the dataset. The following is take from spark docs regarding of describe:

```
/**
   * Computes basic statistics for numeric and string columns, including count, mean, stddev, min,
   * and max. If no columns are given, this function computes statistics for all numerical or
   * string columns.
   *
   * This function is meant for exploratory data analysis, as we make no guarantee about the
   * backward compatibility of the schema of the resulting Dataset. If you want to
   * programmatically compute summary statistics, use the `agg` function instead.
   *
   * {{{
   *   ds.describe("age", "height").show()
   *
   *   // output:
   *   // summary age   height
   *   // count   10.0  10.0
   *   // mean    53.3  178.05
   *   // stddev  11.6  15.7
   *   // min     18.0  163.0
   *   // max     92.0  192.0
   * }}}
   *
   * Use [[summary]] for expanded statistics and control over which statistics to compute.
   *
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. Actually i missed asking the actual question which is - "The describe() gives score column as string where as when i do describe without parentheses or use printSchema() then it gives score column as int - which it is actually.". I have update it now.

Answer (score 0):

In python. both foo.bar and foo.bar() are valid statements, where foo is an object and bar is a method defined in the class representing the object foo. In the former case, you access the method which is bound to foo object but you did not invoke the method.

Now coming to pyspark. The statement df2.describe tell us that it has found a method called describe on the df2 dataframe, which is correct. When you invoke the method describe in df2.describe() you get a new dataframe. You have to invoke the show method on the result to get the statistics, associated with the original dataframe. I would suggest to run the following 3 commands in succession.

```
df2.describe
df2.describe()
df2.describe().show()
```

Answer (score 0):

describe() is snot the schema of the data set, it contains the statistics of the data set (max, min, mean, stedv, ..). it even has an additional column called summary. SparkSQL stores these data in a string format as a SQPRK SQL data frame. printSchema() refelcest the type of the columns. So these two are complenearty of each other.